# Using SQL, Populate a daily status report based on few historical data of points

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Description: In search of an efficient solution to the following problem, I want to create a daily report which shows current and historical data on a particular observation. Any help is highly appreciated

```
status_history
+--------------------+-------------+--------------+------------+
|         id         | report_date | status_start | status_end |
+--------------------+-------------+--------------+------------+
| 0034x00000RX4G7AAL | 2022-03-21  | TRUE         | FALSE      |
| 0034x00000RX4G7AAL | 2022-03-24  | FALSE        | TRUE       |
+--------------------+-------------+--------------+------------+
```

In addition to the above table assume that you have a table with daily dates.
Which is being used as a left table to join data from status history.

```
-- a series of dates (daily)
select 
    date_at
from 
    mydb.calendar.dim_calendar
```

desired result set

```
+--------------------+------------+-------------+--------------+------------+
|         id         |    date    | report_date | status_start | status_end |
+--------------------+------------+-------------+--------------+------------+
| 0034x00000RX4G7AAL | 2022-03-18 | #N/A        | #N/A         | #N/A       |
| 0034x00000RX4G7AAL | 2022-03-19 | #N/A        | #N/A         | #N/A       |
| 0034x00000RX4G7AAL | 2022-03-20 | #N/A        | #N/A         | #N/A       |
| 0034x00000RX4G7AAL | 2022-03-21 | 2022-03-21  | TRUE         | FALSE      |
| 0034x00000RX4G7AAL | 2022-03-22 | 2022-03-21  | TRUE         | FALSE      |
| 0034x00000RX4G7AAL | 2022-03-23 | 2022-03-21  | TRUE         | FALSE      |
| 0034x00000RX4G7AAL | 2022-03-24 | 2022-03-24  | FALSE        | TRUE       |
| 0034x00000RX4G7AAL | 2022-03-25 | 2022-03-24  | FALSE        | TRUE       |
| 0034x00000RX4G7AAL | 2022-03-26 | 2022-03-24  | FALSE        | TRUE       |
| 0034x00000RX4G7AAL | 2022-03-27 | 2022-03-24  | FALSE        | TRUE       |
| 0034x00000RX4G7AAL | 2022-03-28 | 2022-03-24  | FALSE        | TRUE       |
| 0034x00000RX4G7AAL | 2022-03-29 | 2022-03-24  | FALSE        | TRUE       |
| 0034x00000RX4G7AAL | 2022-03-30 | 2022-03-24  | FALSE        | TRUE       |
| 0034x00000RX4G7AAL | 2022-03-31 | 2022-03-24  | FALSE        | TRUE       |
+--------------------+------------+-------------+--------------+------------+
```

my solution gives me the desired result but I don't find the logic elegant. I was trying to do it using join conditions but couldn't figure it out.

```
with daily as ( 
select 
    date_at
from 
    mydb.calendar.dim_calendar 
where
    1=1
    and date_at between '2021-05-24' AND current_date)



, student_onboarding_status as ( 
select 
    distinct student_id 
from 
    mydb.report_students.students_status_log_sf
where
    1=1
    and student_id='0034x00000RX4G7AAL')


, generate_daily_student as (

    select 
        att.student_id as student_id
        , daily.date_at
    from 
        student_onboarding_status as att
        cross join daily as daily


)

-- select * from generate_daily_student

, daily_student_status as ( 
select 
    *,
    last_value(aos.student_id ignore nulls)  over(partition by gda.student__id order by date_at 
    rows BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as attorney_id__,
    last_value(aos.report_date ignore nulls)  over(partition by gda.student__id order by date_at 
    rows BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as report_date__,
    last_value(aos.STATUS_BEGINNING_OF_DAY ignore nulls)  over(partition by gda.student__id order by date_at 
    rows BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as status_beginning_of_day__
    last_value(aos.STATUS_END_OF_DAY ignore nulls)  over(partition by gda.student__id order by date_at 
    rows BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as status_end_of_day__
from 
    generate_daily_student as gda
    left join mydb.report_students.attorney_status_log_sf as aos
    on gda.date_at = aos.report_date
    and gda.student__id = aos.student_id
where 
    1=1
)


select * from daily_student_status
order by date_at asc
```

Comment: also it would be good to post what you have tried so far.

Comment: That's pretty much the way to generate all possible combinations. You can certainly express that inline with the cte if that feels shorter.

Answer (score 0):

LAG needs to be used here. If NULLS are ok in place of #N/A, then following can be used. Little more work, sure NULLS can also be replaced.

```
select daily_date,
lag(id) ignore nulls over (order by daily_date) as id,
lag(report_date) ignore nulls over (order by daily_date) as report_date,
lag(status_start) ignore nulls over (order by daily_date) as status_start,
lag(status_end) ignore nulls over (order by daily_date) as status_end
from
(select daily_date,id,report_date,status_start,status_end
from dt_dim left join status_history
ON
DAILY_DATE=report_date
ORDER BY daily_date
);
+------------+--------------------+-------------+--------------+------------+
| DAILY_DATE | ID                 | REPORT_DATE | STATUS_START | STATUS_END |
|------------+--------------------+-------------+--------------+------------|
| 2022-02-23 | NULL               | NULL        | NULL         | NULL       |
| 2022-02-24 | NULL               | NULL        | NULL         | NULL       |
| 2022-02-25 | NULL               | NULL        | NULL         | NULL       |
| 2022-02-26 | NULL               | NULL        | NULL         | NULL       |
| 2022-02-27 | NULL               | NULL        | NULL         | NULL       |
| 2022-02-28 | NULL               | NULL        | NULL         | NULL       |
| 2022-03-01 | NULL               | NULL        | NULL         | NULL       |
| 2022-03-02 | NULL               | NULL        | NULL         | NULL       |
| 2022-03-03 | NULL               | NULL        | NULL         | NULL       |
| 2022-03-04 | NULL               | NULL        | NULL         | NULL       |
| 2022-03-05 | NULL               | NULL        | NULL         | NULL       |
| 2022-03-06 | NULL               | NULL        | NULL         | NULL       |
| 2022-03-07 | NULL               | NULL        | NULL         | NULL       |
| 2022-03-08 | NULL               | NULL        | NULL         | NULL       |
| 2022-03-09 | NULL               | NULL        | NULL         | NULL       |
| 2022-03-10 | NULL               | NULL        | NULL         | NULL       |
| 2022-03-11 | NULL               | NULL        | NULL         | NULL       |
| 2022-03-12 | NULL               | NULL        | NULL         | NULL       |
| 2022-03-13 | NULL               | NULL        | NULL         | NULL       |
| 2022-03-14 | NULL               | NULL        | NULL         | NULL       |
| 2022-03-15 | NULL               | NULL        | NULL         | NULL       |
| 2022-03-16 | NULL               | NULL        | NULL         | NULL       |
| 2022-03-17 | NULL               | NULL        | NULL         | NULL       |
| 2022-03-18 | NULL               | NULL        | NULL         | NULL       |
| 2022-03-19 | NULL               | NULL        | NULL         | NULL       |
| 2022-03-20 | NULL               | NULL        | NULL         | NULL       |
| 2022-03-21 | NULL               | NULL        | NULL         | NULL       |
| 2022-03-22 | 0034x00000RX4G7AAL | 2022-03-21  | True         | False      |
| 2022-03-23 | 0034x00000RX4G7AAL | 2022-03-21  | True         | False      |
| 2022-03-24 | 0034x00000RX4G7AAL | 2022-03-21  | True         | False      |
| 2022-03-26 | 0034x00000RX4G7AAL | 2022-03-24  | False        | True       |
| 2022-03-27 | 0034x00000RX4G7AAL | 2022-03-24  | False        | True       |
| 2022-03-28 | 0034x00000RX4G7AAL | 2022-03-24  | False        | True       |
| 2022-03-29 | 0034x00000RX4G7AAL | 2022-03-24  | False        | True       |
| 2022-03-30 | 0034x00000RX4G7AAL | 2022-03-24  | False        | True       |
| 2022-03-31 | 0034x00000RX4G7AAL | 2022-03-24  | False        | True       |
| 2022-04-01 | 0034x00000RX4G7AAL | 2022-03-24  | False        | True       |
+------------+--------------------+-------------+--------------+------------+
```